# Run Android application as Shell User

Tags: android, linux, shell

In my application, I need to start a native binary that opens and read from some `/sys/kernel files`. If I launch the native binary by connecting using adb shell (launching manually from `/data/local/tmp`), then everything works fine.

I would like the App to programmatically do two things,

1. Copy the binary to `/data/local/tmp/`. Again this wont work as the normal android app doesnt have enough privileges.
2. Start the binary as a shell user so I can have the necessary privileges. I have tried using `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.shell` , but that doesnt seem to work.

Please note that I don't need root to open the `/sys` files.
All I need is to be shell user. 
Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `shell` UID is reserved for development and testing. Running an app with `shell` privileges is circumventing Google's security model. So you will not be able do it on a secured commercial device without *rooting* it.

A possible temporary (non-persistent between reboots) workaround would be:

1. Use `adb shell` to start a background service process, running as shell UID
2. In your application, using IPC to ask the service to perform special task for you

Comment: Thats exactly what we are doing now :(

Comment: Sorry, there is no former way of doing this on a normal Android devices since Google don't give us a chance to "sudo".

Comment: Not "Google", it's Android security.