# Switch to UID 2000 (shell) in an Android app programmatically?

Tags: android, shell, adb, uid

I already know how to switch to any UID when a `su` binary is available.

```
su 2000
```

My question is, is it possible to switch to UID 2000 (and keep it persistent after a reboot), when a `su` binary / root privileges are not available, with an Android app (programmatically, preferably Java), if the device user gives permission to do so?

(An idea, will it be possible to craft a virtual USB device and run ADB in the context of that device, and get the shell UID?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20242865/1778421

Comment: Already tried that, but, what I want is persistence after reboot, and that is not persistent because the process will get resetted after a reboot. Any ideas for keep that persistent?

Comment: It is okay if that requires verification again, or even one time PC setup, but that method requires connecting to PC every time the user wants to get shell privileges.

Comment: that answer still holds true even if you don't like it. `shell` UID is reserved for development and testing. Running an app with `shell` privileges is circumventing Google's security model no matter how you dress that up